# Don't reset dynamical select on reload

Tags: javascript, html

I populated a select dynamically using javascript:

```
 function fill() {
   var select = document.getElementById("test");
   select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("A");
   select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("B");
   select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("C");
 }
```

Is there a way to prevent the select from resetting after reload? Or is there a better way to create a select multiple times without copying the same HTML code over and over?

Comment: Once you reload the page, everything is reset, you'll need persistent storage to overcome that.

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp / html5 web storage.

Comment: When I have a static select and I press F5 in Firefox to reload the page it will save the selected item. Only if I reset the cache by using Ctrl+F5 it resets the selected item.